# C# Chart Column Alignment

Tags: c#, charts

I have a problem with aligning columns.
That's problem here:

[image]

I want alignment like this.

[image]

Code Here:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Auto = false;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.X = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height = 90;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Width = 90;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AlignmentStyle = AreaAlignmentStyles.All;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.All;
for (int i = 2002;i<2017;i++)
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(No) AS Sayı FROM [main$] WHERE [Yil]="+i+"", con);
            komut.Connection = con;
            OleDbDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                chart1.Series.Add(dr["Sayı"].ToString());
                chart1.Series[dr["Sayı"].ToString()].Points.AddXY(i, float.Parse(dr["Sayı"].ToString()));
                chart1.Series[i2].Color = Color.Black;
                chart1.Series[i2]["PixelPointWidth"] = "100";
                chart1.Series[i2].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "####" + ((char)160) + "\n";
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "####" + ((char)160) + "\n";           
                i2 += 1;
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Show your code what you have done.

Comment: Looks like you have failed to add data to the other series. Columns are always centered around their common x-value, even if some data are missing! - And: Why do keep adding more and more series in the reader loop??? You most likely should only add datapoints there to __one and the same series__, no?

Comment: I want the like that chart: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEZZt.png

Comment: Sure. Then do as I told you and take out the series creation from the loop!! That chart in the link has only __one__ series after all!

Comment: OK, next monday i will try it.

Comment: I'm sorry to be late, I've tried it the way you want and you're very smart! Edit:https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMI9n.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank You @TaW
Solution:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
     chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(i,float.Parse(dr["Sayi"].ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Please add that code top the question! This is not an answer!!